# How can I calculate the rating of multiple Nodes?

Tags: computer-science

I have four nodes, that sends numbers between 1 and 10000 to the main-node.
The value of every node should be between certain numbers:

$$10 < node1 < 15$$
$$12 < node2 < 45$$
$$50 < node3 < 76$$
$$800 < node4 < 1200$$

Use case 1: Ideal set of nodes, would look like this:
$$node1 = 12$$
$$node1 = 15$$
$$node1 = 55$$
$$node1 = 850$$

Use case 2: Non-ideal set would be:
$$node1 = 20$$
$$node1 = 15$$
$$node1 = 55$$
$$node1 = 850$$

As you can see, every node, except node1, sends the right values.

Now I want to take the values of all nodes, put into a formula and get a number, that can tell me, if every node has the ideal value or that at least one node is over the range, like in use case 2.

$$IdealMinValue < f(node1, node2, node3, node4) < IdealMaxValue $$
or
$$f(node1, node2, node3, node4) \approx IdealValue$$

Answer (score 0):

For each node, define a function that returns True if the node is in tolerance and False otherwise.  Then take the conjunction of the four.  A False for the conjunction means one is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion:-Will delete later if someone comes up with a better function.
We know that $(x-a)(x-b) <0$ when $a<x<b$ and $(x-a)(x-b)>0$ for $x$ not in $(a,b)$.Note that $(a,b)$ are min and max values for a particular node.
From this you can define a function for every node and have a sort of "boolean function" to check if all the functions return negative values . In this case it will have "True Value" ie all of them are negative otherwise False.